# Error Installing Oracle Database Client 12c

Tags: oracle

Getting this error While installing Oracle Database Client 12c Release 1

```
Error in writing to file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\\..\..\Xml\Schemas\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.Configuration.Section.xsd'. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\..\..\Xml\Schemas\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.Configuration.Section.xsd (Access is denied)]
```

Any fix for this ?

Comment: Are you running the installer as an administrator?

Comment: Yes! using administrator

Comment: run the installer with option **run as administrator** ( even you are an admin).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here. Even after running as administrator, I still had to locate the file, in my case at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\Schemas" open properties window and uncheck read only (remember to aply the configuration to the subfolders and files). Hope it helps.

Comment: under \Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 there is no Xml folder